# C++ File I/O with Multiple Files

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

How can I check what text files exist in a directory and get the names of the text files in that directory in C++.

My aim is to list the textfiles in a specific directory and let the user load one of the files.

I'm using Windows.

My last code looks like this:

```
ListAllTxtFiles(L"C:\\Users\\Tnc\Desktop\\Yazılım Çalışmaları\\Projects\\Oyun Projem\\data\\SaveFiles\\");

void CObjectHandling::ListAllTxtFiles(const wchar_t *Directory)
{
    TCHAR Buffer[2048];
    wsprintf(Buffer, L"s%*.txt", Directory);//there are security considerations about this function

    WIN32_FIND_DATAW FindData;
    HANDLE FileHandle = FindFirstFileW(Buffer, &FindData);

    if (FileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Could not find any files..\n");
    }
    else
    {
        do 
        {
            printf("Found %s\\%s\n", Directory, FindData.cFileName);
            // Do stuff with your text file here...
        } while (FindNextFile(FileHandle, &FindData));
        CloseHandle(FileHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "files exist in a file"? Did you mean "files exist in a directory"?

Comment: Ordinarily, especially in Unix, directories a.k.a. folders contain files, and sub-directories (sub-folders). Files contain data. Windows does have a number of notions of files within files, but that's not supported by the C++ standard library (you can use the Windows API to access such streams). Likewise, old Mac, and possibly still in OS X, had a notion of file "forks". I don't know much about it, but if it's still there then you can use the OS X API for that. Finally there are many kinds of archives, e.g. zip, with files in a single file. Is that it?

Comment: Summing up, you need to **clarify your question**. If it's really about files within files, then please do specify the particular such notion (e.g. Windows, Mac, or some kind of archive). Or else, use common terminology where directories are never called files.

Comment: Completely unclear question. I've even tried to extrapolate file paths read from a configuration file, but cannot give a cocise answer.

Comment: Reading and iterating through directories is platform specific, so which platform are you using (hint:  some platforms don't have file systems)?

Comment: Please clarify "load that file into the program".  How? Are they textual data files or binary files?  Are you going to memory map them?  Are you going to have more than one file open at a time?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: No, directory handling is supported by Boost Filesystem, which will be part of C++17 standard library.

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard library does not contain any concept of directories, you would need to resort to the native platform APIs, or another library such as boost(which will then call those APIs for you). Since you did not specify what platform you're using, and since I can not comment on your question, I will give suggestions for Windows.

You can use [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx), on Windows, which allows you to get a handle to the first file that matches some string, such as "*.txt" in your case. To find further files, you can use [FindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx), which allows you to iterate over a all files in a particular directory, you can even quite easily implement something that does this recurisvely, should you want to have text files in sub folders.

```
void
ListAllTxtFiles(const char *Directory)
{
    char Buffer[2048];
    sprintf(Buffer, "%s*.txt", Directory);

    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;
    HANDLE FileHandle = FindFirstFile(Buffer, &FindData);

    if (FileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Could not find any files..\n");
    }
    else
    {
        do 
        {
            printf("Found %s\\%s\n", Directory, FindData.cFileName);
            // Do stuff with your text file here...
        } while (FindNextFile(FileHandle, &FindData));
        CloseHandle(FileHandle);
    }
}
```

You can call this function like

```
ListAllTxtFiles("path\\to\\my\\text\\files\\");
```

with the trailing backslashes.

Comment: I'm using windows, if you could write a sample code I would appriciate it. Thanks

Comment: I've added a very basic code sample that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks. This code will be really helpful

Comment: No problem, I also edited your question so it is a bit more clear what you're asking, and don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: at the line HANDLE FileHandle = FindFirstFile(Buffer, &FindData); I get the error: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char (*)[2048]' to 'LPCWSTR' What's the cause of this?Is there any tutorials you can suggest on win32 api programming?

Comment: The reason is that you're compiling your application as a unicode application, my code assumes standard ASCII text, but you can easily change that. You could type #undef UNICODE, above this code, which forces ASCII functions, or you could change the type of the array to TCHAR(that would require using wsprintf instead of sprintf as well).  As far as tutorials are concerned, I would probably suggest this good old book: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Edition-Developer-Reference/dp/157231995X.